# How to use SHCreateShellFolderView from C# code on Windows 7?

Tags: c#, winapi

I'm trying to write a shell extension using C# however I haven't found any example on the web about how to use [SHCreateShellFolderView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762141(VS.85).aspx) windows API function. Does anyone has some example of how to use it?

I'm trouble to use it on Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to take a look at codeproject [C# does Shell, Part 1](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/csdoesshell1.aspx) and [Namespace Extensions: The Tasks Band Disclosed](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/foldertasks.aspx). First article introduces shell programming with C#, and second one is about how to use SHCreateShellFolderView with unmanaged C++.

Comment: Do you have a C# specific example?

Comment: No I don't. It looks like Microsoft recommends against writing managed shell extensions and does not consider them a supported scenario http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/magazine/cc188741.aspx. But anyway is possible to create unmanaged component for that and access it with managed wrapper.

Comment: I was aware of this recommendation, but it was stated before the CLR v4.0. On CLR v4.0 there is a feature called in process side-by-side execution which make it possible for a process to load more than one version of the CLR at the time. So, if you write your extension using C# 4.0 there is no problem.

Comment: I don't know if that will help you, but just have picked first googled item by using "SHCreateShellFolderView DllImport" as key http://us.generation-nt.com/question-about-shcreateshellfolderview-drag-drop-drop-nse-fine-but-drag-nse-dropsource-problem-help-25808062.html